# Multiple relations like join tables (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j

How do I express the following in neo4j?

match or create user bob; bob works at studio; while at studio, he's allowed to doodle; while at studio, he's also allowed to type.

Here's what I have:

```
MERGE (u:user {name:'bob'})
MERGE (c:company {name: 'studio'})
MERGE (u)-[:works_at]->(c)-[:allowed_to]->(p:permission {name:'doodle'})
MERGE (u)-[:works_at]->(c)-[:allowed_to]->(p:permission {name:'type'})
```

This doesn't work as permission becomes a relation of company.

Also, is it possible to chain relations such that:

```
MERGE work=(u)-[:works_at]->(c)
CREATE (work)-[:allowed_to]->(p:permission {name:'doodle'})
CREATE (work)-[:allowed_to]->(p:permission {name:'type'})
```

where you assign a relation to a variable to continue it later on in another query?

Comment: Can you close the 2 other identical questions that you created?

Comment: Stackoverflow was bugging out. Wasn't me. I didn't realize it created others. I closed them. Thanks for making me aware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about modelling it so the company grants the permission? Something like this...

```
MERGE (u:user {name:'bob'})
MERGE (c:company {name: 'studio'})
MERGE (u)-[:works_at]->(c)
MERGE (u)-[:allowed_to]->(p1:permission {name:'doodle'})<-[:GRANTS]-(c)
MERGE (u)-[:allowed_to]->(p2:permission {name:'type'})<-[:GRANTS]-(c)
RETURN *
```

You can't really refer to objects via identifiers/variables you have created previously in other queries. You would have to re-match or merge those previously created objects in your new query.

Part 2 could be modelled something like this..

```
MERGE (u:user {name:'bob'})
MERGE (c:company {name: 'studio'})
MERGE (u)-[:DOES]->(work:Work {start_date: timestamp()} )-[:AT]->(c)
CREATE (work)-[:allowed_to]->(p:permission {name:'doodle'})
CREATE (work)-[:allowed_to]->(p:permission {name:'type'})
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate, if you never need to lookup all users with a certain permission at a company, you could maintain a collection of permissions as relationship properties.

```
MERGE (u:user {name:'bob'})
MERGE (c:company {name: 'studio'})
MERGE (u)-[r:works_at]->(c)
SET r.permissions = ['doodle', 'type']
```